# How to insert a row in tableView without using reloadData function in Cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview, reloaddata

I been working on a self taught project in `Cocoa`. Trying to replicate how the media player playlist works(Play,Add and Delete and etc...).

So far, I have managed to populate a tableview from the directory using `NSOpenPanel`. I can able to insert a new files to the tableview and play selected sound files using `AVAudioPlayer`. Everything works as expected.

But When, I try to insert a new row to the tableView **while the audioPlayer is playing**. It updates the entire tableView and i am getting the following issues.

- audioPlayer stopped as soon as the update performed.
- Playing selected media file left unselected.

**My Partial code below:**

```
   var items: [URL] = [] {
   didSet {    
          tableView.beginUpdates()
          tableView.reloadData(forRowIndexes: tableView.selectedRowIndexes, columnIndexes: tableView.selectedColumnIndexes)
          tableView.reloadData()//Trying to avoid this func...
          tableView.selectRowIndexes(tableView.selectedRowIndexes, byExtendingSelection: true)
          tableView.endUpdates()
     }
   }
```

> How do i update the tableView by adding or deleting row while the
>   audioPlayer performing and not to reload the entire tableview.

I have done some research as below and found similar question to above issues. But it didn't helped me to fix the issue entirely.

[How to update NSTableView without using -reloadData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977454/how-to-update-nstableview-without-using-reloaddata)

[reloadData in NSTableView but keep current selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248242/reloaddata-in-nstableview-but-keep-current-selection)

[Apple Doc - reloadData(forRowIndexes:columnIndexes:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1527621-reloaddata)

I am new to macOS development. So, help me to understand the issue and how to fix it.

---

### **Update:**

Below code solves part of the issue mentioned above. Using below code keeps the selected row highlighted after update.

```
  var items: [URL] = [] {
  didSet {    
      let selectedRowIndexes = self.tableView.selectedRowIndexes
      tableView.reloadData()
      tableView.selectRowIndexes(selectedRowIndexes, byExtendingSelection: true)
     }
   }
```

But, Still audioPlayer stopped after inserting new row for some reason. my audioPlayer code as below

**In ViewDidLoad:** (action method)

```
 tableView.doubleAction = #selector(tableViewClick)
```

**Selector code:**

```
 func tableViewClick(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if tableView.selectedRow < 0 { return }
    let selectedItem = items[tableView.selectedRow]
    print(selectedItem)
    do{
        try self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: selectedItem)
        audioPlayer.delegate = self
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    catch {
        print("Error reading file attributes")
    }
}
```

Trying to update row/column only using **reloadData(forRowIndexes:columnIndexes:)**. But, it not seems to be working...

```
  tableView.reloadData(forRowIndexes: NSIndexSet(index: tableView.selectedRowIndexes.count) as IndexSet, columnIndexes: NSIndexSet(index: tableView.selectedColumnIndexes.count) as IndexSet)
```

or

```
  tableView.reloadData(forRowIndexes: tableView.selectedRowIndexes, columnIndexes: tableView.selectedColumnIndexes)
```

---

### Update: **Issue Resolved:**

Issue resolved after `@Leo Dabus` suggestion and his accepted answer from this post [BLE Peripheral disconnects when navigating to different ViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477776/ble-peripheral-disconnects-when-navigating-to-different-viewcontroller/47481780#47481780) . I created Singleton class as below

```
class Shared { 
    private init(){ } 
    static let instance = Shared()
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
}
```

And access the same instance as below.

```
Shared.instance.audioPlayer = audioPlayer
```

Hope this helps someone....

Comment: Why is the AVAudioPlayer stopping?  is it owned by a tableViewCell? if so maybe move it to the view controller or to an AudioPlayerPool class and delegate back the respondsibility for starting the player.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i will try and  I dont have any seperate class for AudioPlayer. but i do have a tableview action method  in viewDidLoad `tableView.action = #selector(tableViewClick)`

Comment: New rows are automatically updated. Just insert or remove the row.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks. I have no problem inserting or removing rows.problem is why the audioPlayer stop running after row insert. check my update and let me know on comment.

Comment: Why do you do `reloadData`?

Comment: @Willeke Thanks. I am bit confused. how can i add a new row without  reload func. i tried without reload func but nothing get called...

Comment: Insert a row in the table view with `insertRows(at:withAnimation:)`.